# Disabling docker image tag updating

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Is there any way in either the docker registry API or quay API to disable updating of image tags once they are pushed? The reasoning would be so others using a tagged image don't have it switched out from under them without their knowledge. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images will only be swapped out under you if you do a pull, so you may be able to solve your issue by avoiding any pulls.

When you need to be certain you are using the same image and can't control the registry server yourself, I'd recommend pulling by the sha256 hash instead of the tag. By design, I don't believe any registry servers restrict overwriting the tag, but the sha256 will always be the same.

To get the sha256 for your image, you can run:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .RepoDigests }}' yourimage
```

And then you can pull by the sha256 with the following syntax:

```
docker pull busybox@sha256:a59906e33509d14c036c8678d687bd4eec81ed7c4b8ce907b888c607f6a1e0e6
```

Note, there are multiple hashes in the inspect output, you'll want the RepoDigests entry, and this will not exist before you've pushed the image to a registry.